# adding new field to contact.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I bought a WP theme a few months ago and it works great! I am trying to edit the contact.php / sendmail.php

I have successfully added in a field, it shows up in the body of the email and sends correctly. However, I am have a lot of trouble getting the new field "school(s) of interest" to highlight properly (with hidden text) when the field hasn't been filled. The contact form in question can be found here: http://www.northbrookmontessori.org/school-tours/

**sendmail.php**

```
<?php
    //validate fields
$errors = '';

//has the form's submit button been pressed?
if( !empty( $_POST['myformsubmit'] ) )
{
    // HAS THE SPAM TRAP FIELD BEEN FILLED IN?
    if( !empty( $_POST['favouriteColour'] ) )
    {
        exit;
    }

$myemail = $_POST['youremail'];
$thankyou = $_POST['thankyou'];
$formerror = $_POST['formerror'];
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['school']) ||
   empty($_POST['email']) ||
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$school = $_POST['school']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if (!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email_address)) { $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address"; } //send email

if( empty($errors))
{
   $to = $myemail; 
   $email_subject = "Contact form submission from $name";
   $email_body = "$name has sent you this email through the contact form: \n \n".
   "Name: $name \n".
   "School(s) of interest: $school \n".
   "Email: $email_address \nMessage: \n\n$message";

   $headers = "From: $email_address"; 

   mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
   //redirect to the 'thank you' page
   header('Location: ' . $thankyou);
}
else {
   header('Location: ' . $formerror);
   }

}

?>
```

**contact.php**

```
<!-- ***** CONTACT -->
<div class="block_wrapper <?php if($bb_animation == 'yes'){ echo 'animation' . $anim1_number; ?> animated <?php } ?><?php echo ' '.$custom_width; ?>">

    <div class="box_full<?php if($margin_top != ''){echo ' ' . $margin_top;} ?><?php if($margin_bottom != ''){echo ' ' . $margin_bottom;} ?><?php if($custom_classes != NULL){echo ' ' . $custom_classes;} ?>">

    <form id="theform" class="form mt35" method="post" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/sendmail.php">

    <p class="hRow">
        <label for="favouriteColour">Favourite colour (do not fill in)</label>
        <span><input type="text" name="favouriteColour" id="favouriteColour" value="" /></span>
    </p>

    <input type="hidden" name="youremail" id="youremail" value="<?php if(!empty($contact_email)){echo $contact_email;} ?>" />

    <input type="hidden" name="thankyou" id="thankyou" value="<?php if(!empty($contact_thankyou)){echo $contact_thankyou;} ?>" />

    <input type="hidden" name="formerror" id="formerror" value="<?php if(!empty($contact_error)){echo $contact_error;} ?>" />

    <p class="name validated">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <span><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></span>
    </p>

    <p class="school validated">
        <label for="school">School(s) of interest</label>
        <span><input type="text" name="school" id="school" /></span>
    </p>

    <p class="email validated">
        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        <span><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></span>
    </p>

    <p class="text validated">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="50" cols="100"></textarea>
    </p>

    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" class="buttonmedium float_r" name="myformsubmit" value="Send Email" />
    </p>
    <p id="error">* There were errors on the form, please re-check the fields.</p>
    </form>

    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

</div><!-- ***** END CONTACT -->
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to go to the file:

http://www.northbrookmontessori.org/wp-content/themes/modular/js/settings.js?ver=4.2.2

and edit the top where it says:

> // Place ID's of all required fields here.

add in **school**

Comment: Dagon!! That did it...you are a life saver!